# What's the good write to display this json form in angular 13

Tags: html, json, angular, typescript

So to be simple i've got in json this:[response img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4vKNW.png) my classes are :

```
export class Operation {
       operations?: (OperationDetail);//change by OperationDetail[]
     }
     export interface OperationDetail {
            id?: string;
            titre?: any;
            description?: any;
            debut?: any;
            fin?: any;
            statut?: any;
            etat?: any;
            notification?: any;
            alerte?: any;
            ouvrages?: any;
            chefEus?: BigInt;
            donneurOrdres?: any;
            linkedOperations?: number[];

}
```

my service to get my operation:

```
getOperations(): Observable<Operation>{
    return  this.http.get<Operation>(this.operationUrl)
          .pipe(map(response=> ({
          operations: response.operations,
         })
            ),
          );
  }
```

in html i try different thing but i'm sure that this: {{ operations.operations.id }} tell me that he is undefined but right in my class OperationDetail that i wanna display. So after many research i search someone to end this mystery pls ;)

Update:

Hello i finally did it by passing my (OperationDetail) in OperationDetail[]. then in my html i ngFor like that to take the data.
loop:

```
<div *ngFor="let operation of operations?.operations">
  <p class="left"> Titre: {{ operation?.titre }}</p>
</div>
```

Thanks everyone for your speed ;)

Comment: Hello, you talk about JSON and yet show a screenshot of an javascript object. Also you did not provide any code for us to check. Please also know that you can copy/paste codes here instead of pictures.

Comment: yeah sorry for the first post i'll make it clear :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with an array :

```
operations?: OperationsDetails[];
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that's an `async` pipe to add, or an add of question mark before the dot to tolerate `null|undef` values.

```
{{ operations.operations.id }} --> {{ operations?.operations?.id }}
```

Comment: is that the show use html you want?``` <div class="container-list" *ngFor="let operation of operations;let index;">

  <p class="left"> Titre: {{ operation.titre }}</p>
</div>```

Comment: I did it by making it in a table thanks but it might work actually from the error i had by trying.